# Appending some processing to another Gradle task

Tags: gradle, build

I want to extend javadoc by one file generated from Java. With Gradle, I could solve it only as

```
task extradoc(type: JavaExec) {
    ... do it
}

javadoc {
    dependsOn: extradoc
}
```

This feels wrong for the following reasons:

- I want no task, all the `extradoc` is just an addendum and there's no point in generating it separately.
- Especially, there's no reason to clutter the task list by some minor things.
- I'd actually like to generate it after `javadoc`. I could do this by reversing the `dependsOn` relation, but then I'd have to call `extradoc` instead of `javadoc` which feels stupid.

---

I obviously tried

```
javadoc {
    doLast {extradoc}
}
```

but this did nothing at all. Why???

This "extradoc" thing is actually something I could live with. What's much worse is that I seem to miss some fundamental understanding of how Gradle works.

*<rant>Befroe someone points me to the few hundreds pages of Gradle doc: I hoped to be able to do some basic things before I read them all.</rant>*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a Finalizer task to `javadoc` as follows:

```
task extradoc(type: JavaExec) {
    // ... do something
}

javadoc.finalizedBy extradoc
```

See the [Gradle Documentation on Tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#N10F3E) for more detail.